# What is the difference between Quaternions and Bicomplex Numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions, hypercomplex-numbers

So, I know Quaternions are basically 4 dimensional Complex numbers, and the dimensions can double forever to Octonions, Sedinions, etc. I recently heard about bicomplex numbers, which are also sort of 4 dimensional complex numbers. I looked into it a bit, and I found that bicomplex numbers are a commutative version of quaternions. But I wanted to know how exactly that works. How is the multiplication defined? Also can that be extended to 8-Dimensional biquaternions, 16-D bioctonions, etc? And how are those defined exactly? I know with regular hypercomplex numbers, you lose properties as you go up in dimensions, so does the same thing happen with the bi- ones? If so does it just lose the property that it would normally lose one dimension lower? Or do they not lose properties at all? Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quaternions are basically 4 dimensional **real** numbers?

Comment: Well, however you want to say I guess. I was more just saying that I knew what Quaternions were, not trying to give an in-depth description. Really they are their own thing, 4-Dimensional Hypercomplex Numbers.

Answer (score 8):

I'd never heard of a bicomplex number, but I like algebra, so let's go for it. From what I understand, reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicomplex_number) and playing around:

We assume that, in addition to $i$, our favorite square root of $-1$, we have another, $h$, so that $h^2 = -1 = i^2$. Further, we force $i$ and $h$ to commute, so that $ih = hi$.

You can see for yourself that $(ih)^2 = 1$, since $h$ and $i$ commute. So, $ih$ is a square root of $1$. We know of some other square roots of $1$, let's see what happens when we multiply something by $ih$. At this point, we'll assume our numbers are associative (just like we assumed $h$ and $i$ commute).

$(ih)h = ih^2 = i(-1) = -i$. Thus, multiplication by $ih$ sent $h$ to $-i$. This means $ih$ can't be $1$ or $-1$, the square roots of $1$ we already know and love, since $i$ and $h$ are distinct (that is, $h \neq -i$).

It turns out the set $\{1, i, h, ih\}$ forms a basis for these numbers. Thus, a generic "bicomplex number" looks like $a + bi + ch + dih$.

But, these bicomplex numbers are certainly don't act like quaternions. For one, they form a commutative algebra; the order of multiplication never matters! But more seriously, we have zero-divisors:

$$(1 + ih)(-1 + ih) = -1 + ih - ih +(ih)^2 = -1 +ih - ih - 1 = 0.$$

This is a pretty serious departure from the quaternions.

It turns out that the biquaternions are isomorphic to the direct sum $\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$ of the field of complex numbers with itself (here, addition and multiplication are performed component-wise, like vector addition). This is not obvious to me, but it's believable.

Direct sums are fairly uninteresting: Just slap two copies of something together, and there you go! It explains why we have zero-divisors, and commutativity. We just do everything we normally would, but do it twice; business as usual.

The quaternions on the other hand - now that's an algebra! Associative, but not commutative; no zero divisors; we can define a norm. Generally, life with the quaternions is great.

To build the complex numbers, quaternions, or octonians from the reals, the situation is a lot more subtle; the construction is an example of a "twisted group algebra." The complex numbers, quaternions, and octonions are all examples of twisted group algebras over the real numbers. In particular, we get the quaternions by introducing a "twisted" way of multiplying elements of the group algebra $\mathbb{R}[\mathbb{Z}_2^2]$.

Unfortunately, I'm still processing all the details myself, so it's up to you to figure out exactly what "twisting" something entails. Essentially, it's like a direct sum, but with the terms interacting multiplicatively more than just "component-wise," we need some extra magic thrown in.

---

Sources:

John Baez' [write up](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/baezocto.pdf) on octonions, where I first saw the term "twisted group algebra." Lacking on details of the construction, lots of attention to the big picture.

John Bales' [write up](http://jwbales.us/ptgal.pdf) on "Properly Twisted Group Algebras", which is way more detail than I'd hoped for, but could fill in some of the gaps.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that explains it to an extant. They are more different than I expected. Also, I'm glad my question introduced you to something new as well!

Comment: Also, you said $−1+ih−ih+(ih)^2 = −1+ih−ih−1$, when it should be $−1+ih−ih+(ih)^2 = −1+ih−ih+1$

Comment: @RothX Correct you are, and thank you! I'll hold off on changing anything at the moment -- while it is certainly an error, maybe in a day or two I'll be able to improve the post in a more significant way (although probably not :)).

Answer (score 2):

Bicomplex numbers, or tessarines is a commutative algebra as other people said.

It has zero divisors. And I would say, being commutative is a lot more important than disadvantages from zero divisors!

Moreover, zero divisors are not a disadvantage at all, because it allows bicomplex numbers to generalize not only the concept of complex numbers, but also [hyperbolic (split-complex) numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOmQT.png). They are included in bicomplex numbers and have zero divisors.

There is nothing essentially bad regarding zero divisors: this means that we have some elements by which we cannot divide, but we anyway had one such real number: zero.

Unlike what the other answer said, of course there is norm (modulus) in bicomplex numbers.

They [can be represented as real matrices](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262640010_The_Real_Matrices_forms_of_the_Bicomplex_Numbers_and_Homothetic_Exponential_motions) of certain structure with usual matrix operations, so one can experiment with them in any computer algebra system that allows to apply analytic functions to matrices.

[image]

[image]

Images source:https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.527.356&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Despite the zero divisors, what you say about dual numbers is incorrect. There are no nonzero solutions of $z^2=0$ in the bicomplex numbers.

Comment: @J.G. but if one adds dual unity over it, the algebra remains commutative and associative.

Comment: @J.G. This paper describes tessarines and dual hyperbolic: https://www.jcscm.net/fp/126.pdf